# Add tuple as value in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, key

I have a list of tuples with some xml information and want to create a dictionary instead so as to make accesses faster. Need to asign an id as the key I'm storing in the first item for each tuple of the list, and as value all the remaining information but not sure if that is even possible on python.

The code I actually have to generate the list:

```
for node in root.findall('n:graph/n:node', ns):
        id = node.get('id')
        nodes.append((id, *(data.text for data in node if \
        (data.get('key') == keys[2] or data.get('key') == keys[3]))))
```

Which get me the following output:

> nodes = [('id1', 'x', 'y'), ('id2', 'x', 'y') ... ]

What I want is something like:

> nodes = {'id1' : ('x', 'y'), 'id2' : ('x', 'y') ... ]

So that I can then use **if id in nodes** to check if an element exists or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `nodes` as a dictionary and not a list.

```
nodes = {}
for node in root.findall('n:graph/n:node', ns):
        id = node.get('id')
        nodes[id] = tuple([data.text for data in node if \
        (data.get('key') == keys[2] or data.get('key') == keys[3])])
```

Comment: thank u very much, that's what i was looking for never used a dictionary before and didn't know even if what I wanted was possible plus also quite a noob in python.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{x[0]: x[1:] for x in nodes}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nodes = {}
for node in root.findall('n:graph/n:node', ns):
    id = node.get('id')
    nodes[id] = (data.text for data in node if data.get('key') in [keys[2],keys[3]])
```

This will work as long as the ids are guaranteed to be unique, otherwise they will overwrite the older data.

Comment: FYI, `(data.text for data in node if data.get('key') in [keys[2],keys[3]])` will produce a `generator` in Python 3 so you will need to convert it to a `tuple`